# Recording Shared Desktop and Webcam

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, lcds

I want to save published streams on my application server, so I can use the videos to create a webcast presentation later.

Could you please give me some directions to do this? Thanks in advance.

P.S. I may be sounded like I already have an application up and runnning, but I don't. I'm at the planning phase at the moment and trying to decide what/which technology to use.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I get you right...
Recording webcam should be no problem (there are a lot of tutorials), but for recording the desktop (or anything outside your application) you will have to use Adobe AIR, as Flex apps don't allow screenshots or screen recordings because of security limitations.

Comment: I was speaking in context of Adobe Livecycle Collaboration Services. But thanks anyway.